# Open source .net windows form based controls like: gantt chart, calendar and scheduler

Tags: .net, controls, user-interface, toolkit

Is there any open source or free .net ui toolkit containing at least one of the following controls:

2. gantt chart (ms project like)
3. calendar (google calendar like or ms outlook 2003, 2007 like)
4. scheduler (outlook 2007 like)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a free gantt chart from CodeProject. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/Gantt_Chart.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Calendar Dayview like Outlook

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/Calendardayview.aspx

it's not bad at all...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of open source charting libraries:

http://csharp-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting